# PHP errors are not displaying on the page you are developing. You only have SFTP Access to change files. How do you display the errors?

Tags: php

PHP errors are not displaying on the page you are developing. You only have SFTP Access to change files. How do you display the errors?

Answer (score 4):

Try enabling error reporting on top of the script:

```
ini_set ('display_errors', true);
error_reporting (E_ALL);
```

Comment: side note: this won't work for parse errors in the initial script. a) it's another parameter (display_startup_errors) and b) the error occurs before ini_set() is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Per-file change:

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Global change in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 8191
```

Global change in your php.ini file:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `error_reporting` to display all errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

from http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

```
ini_set('error_reporting','On');
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can set the error reporting level on a page-by-page basis by using the error_reporting() function.

E.g.
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Will tell the interpreter to display any errors and warnings it encounters.